# Refilling drop down menu selection after form submission validation

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a sign up/registration form in php that resubmits/retains the users input if everything doesn't validate properly. I've got text box, password input, and radio buttons all working but these drop down menus have been more trouble. The php code I used works for the text boxes but not these select/options, is there a better way to do this? I've cut out the majority of the options just to save space, but each goes from 0-11 months, 1-31 days, and 1900-2013 years respectively.

```
<select id="month" name="month" value="<?php
    if(isset($_POST['month']))
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['month'])?>">

    <option value="default">Month</option>
    <option value="0">January</option>
    ...
    <option value="11">December</option>

</select>
<select id="formDay" name="day" value="<?php
    if(isset($_POST['day']))
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['day'])?>">

    <option value="default">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ...
    <option value="31">31</option>

</select>
<select id="formYear" name="year" value="<?php
    if(isset($_POST['year']))
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['year'])?>">

    <option value="default">Year</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    ...
    <option value="1900">1900</option>

 </select>
```

Comment: do you want to selected the input ?

Comment: Hi, yeah that's pretty much what I want it to do. If my error message shows up saying 'date invalid', I want the users selected values to still be selected and visible (e.g. If they select Feb 29 2013, then when the form reloads/resubmits these values will still be selected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this, generate values dynamically

**Day:**

```
echo "<select name='day'>";
for( $i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++ )
{
    $selectedDay = isset($_POST['day']) && $_POST['day'] == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; 
    echo "<option $selectedDay value=$i>$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

**Month:**

```
$months = array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
echo "<select name='month'>";
for( $i = 0; $i <= 11; $i++ )
{
    $m = $months[$i];
    $selectedMonth = isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] == $i ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; 
    echo "<option $selectedMonth value=$i>$m</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

**Year:**

```
echo "<select name='year'>";
for( $i = 2013; $i >= 1900; $i-- )
{
    $selectedYear = isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year'] == $y ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; 
    echo "<option $selectedYear value=$i>$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

[Demo Normal](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8hux3h) and [Demo Selected](http://codepad.viper-7.com/H4QIRE)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing in the wrong way.

please make the condition inside the each option like below

```
<option value="2013" <?php if(isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year']==2013){ echo "selected";}?>>2013</option>
```

in same manner for month.

Comment: Okay thanks, the only problem with that is that I have a lot of options (over 100 options in years for example), is there a shorter way to implement this for every option?

Comment: yes you can use for loop and generate the dropdown dynamically in that case you need to make only one condition.

Answer (score 1):

With selects you can't set a value ... instead you have to add a selected attribute to the selection option element.

I usually use a function like this to build out my selects

```
function showSelect($name, $options, $selected, $attr = array()){
    $str = "<select name='".$name.'"';
    foreach($attr as $name=>$val){
        $str.= " ".$name."='".$val."'";
    }
    $str.=">";
    foreach($options as $k=>$val){
        $str.= "<option value='".$val."'".($val==$selected?" selected='selected'":"").">".$k.'</option>';
    }
    $str.="</select>";
}
```

$name is the name of the element
$options is an array in the form "option_value"=>"option_label"
$selected is the value of the selection option
$attr is an array of the additional attributes to put on the select element (style id etc.)

For example

```
$days = array();
for($d = 1; $x<=31; $x++){
     $days[(string)$d] = (string)$d;
}

echo showSelect("formDays", $days, $_POST["formDays"], array("id"=>"formDays"));
```

Comment: Ahh okay this looks good. Could you possibly give me an example using my code (maybe days) for what should go where? I'm still pretty new to php.