# Making drop down menu sticky using PHP

Tags: php, html

Below is a drop down menu I made using HTML and PHP. I tried to make the menu sticky but it does not seem to be working. Any ideas about what I should adjust?

```
<select name="month">
<option>Month</option>
<?php $months = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
     if($_POST['month'] != NULL) {
              echo "<option value='" . $_POST['month'] . "'>" . $_POST['month'] . "</option>";
      }
    foreach ($months as $month1){
        echo "<option value='$month1'>$month1</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

I tried using the following code to make which month was selected prior to submitting the form, remain selected after submission:

```
if($_POST['month'] != NULL) {
              echo "<option value='" . $_POST['month'] . "'>" . $_POST['month'] . "</option>";
```

I thought that this would return whatever month the user selected, after submitting the form.

Thank you!

Comment: show, what you've tried to make it **sticky**

Comment: what do you mean by sticky, like stick to the top of the screen or element it is in or when month is selected and the var is passed show the new var selected

Comment: Hey @MasterT, I want the month selected to stick after the form is submitted., so I believe whichever variable is selected prior to submitting. Thank you!

Comment: @ArsalanMithani I have edited my original post. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with setting the default value and remembering the values in select box in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683637/issue-with-setting-the-default-value-and-remembering-the-values-in-select-box-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a lit change to your code if you the property selected to the option html tag will be the first one option not matter the position of the option.

```
    <select name="month">
    <option>Month</option>
    <?php $months = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

        foreach ($months as $month1){
            if(isset($_POST['month']) && $_POST['month'] === $month1) {
                  echo "<option value='" . $month1 . "' selected >" . $month1 . "</option>";
            }else{
                echo "<option value='" . $month1 . "'>" . $month1 . "</option>";
            }

        }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information @Fermin. I tried using the above code, but the drop down menu is now blank. I think this may have to do with the array values. Any ideas?

Comment: @FerminPerdomo thank you! This works perfectly. I really appreciate the help!